# Finding Path Between Two Nodes in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes, args

I have the following simple tree:

[image]

My goal is to find the path between the two manager nodes.

The two nodes will be selected input in the cmd.

So the user might type 'java BinaryTree manager1 manager2' and the output will display the path needed to reach the second manager. This example should output the following:

'Manager1 > Boss < Manager2'

The code I have so far defines the nodes however I need a findPath method to print the path.

CODE: `

```
public class BinaryTree 
    {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Node boss = new Node(1);
  Node manager1 = new Node(2);
  Node manager2 = new Node(3);

  boss.left = manager1;
  boss.right = manager2;

  String path = findPath(args[0], args[1]);
  System.out.println(path);
  } 

 static class Node
 {
  Node left;
  Node right;
  int value;

  public Node(int value)
  {
   this.value = value;
  }
 }
}`
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does your tree have any predictable / exploitable structure?  That is, can you tell whether an entity will be in the left or right sub-tree by any rule?  If not, you'll have no chance but need to do a full traversal of your tree looking where to find the node you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I should have included this, nodes will have id's so for the example above it would be Boss (1), Manager1(2), manager2(3)

Comment: And what is the rule that governs that 2 is the left and 3 the right child of 1?  Clearly, it is not the usual *less than* relation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960057/shortest-path-between-two-nodes-in-an-infinite-complete-binary-tree and http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-distance-two-given-nodes/ might be helpful.

Comment: We can try to little speed up process, by adding to Node parent. Then the best way to find path between managers will be finding the first common ancestor (that can be done in logn - just you are making full path from root to manager1, then full path from root to manager2, then finding last common Node). Then you are just printing path from Manager1 to ancestor, and from ancestor to Manager2.

Comment: I believe a full traversal of the tree is required. Do you have access to any code examples of how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the most general sense, you must find the paths from the root to each node, and merge them together.

How you find the paths depends on the arrangement of the tree; in the worst case it requires a full traversal of the tree.

At the merge step, prune all common ancestors from both paths, but keep track of the nearest common ancestor.  The path you want is the reverse of what's left of the path to manager 1, then the nearest common ancestor ("Boss" in your diagram), then the path to manager 2.

Make sure to accommodate the cases where one manager is an ancestor of the other (the merge procedure I described still works, but one of the trimmed paths will be empty).  Also make sure to trap or accommodate cases where manager 1 == manager 2.

If your tree has structure beyond simple tree topology then it may be possible to optimize some of the above, especially the path-finding.

Comment: I believe a full traversal of the tree is required. Do you have access to any code examples of how to do this? thanks

Comment: The two main choices for a full tree traversal are depth-first search and breadth-first search.  You should find numerous explanations and code samples using those terms.  Your case is slightly special in that you need to remember the path to each node, but that's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program to print the path between 2 nodes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class PrintPath {

    static List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
    static boolean foundBoth;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = Node.createTree();
        printPath(root,9,11);
        System.out.println(path);
    }

    static boolean printPath(Node root,int val1 ,int val2){
        if(root==null){
            return false;
        }
        if(root.data == val1 || root.data == val2){
            addToPath(root);
            if(!foundBoth)
                foundBoth = findDown(root,(root.data==val1)?val2:val1);
            return true;
        }
        if(!foundBoth){
        boolean left = printPath(root.getLeft(), val1, val2);
        if(left){
            addToPath(root);
        }
        boolean right = printPath(root.getRight(), val1, val2);
        if(right)
        addToPath(root);
        return (left|| right);
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }

    private static void addToPath(Node root) {
        path.add(root);
    }


    static boolean findDown(Node root,int val2){
        if(root == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(root.data == val2){
            addToPath(root);
            return true;
        }
        boolean left = findDown(root.getLeft(), val2);
        if(left){
            addToPath(root);
            return true;
        }
        boolean right = findDown(root.getRight(), val2);
        if(right){
            addToPath(root);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This code works fine in finding all the nodes which lie on the path b/w 2 node. I will try and optimize it further and will publish again.