# How to determine the shortest path between two nodes of an infinite, complete binary tree C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, shortest-path

this is my first post on Stack Overflow as I'm quite new to programming.
I'm aware that this question has been asked before but as there was only one answer and it wasn't clear enough for me to understand, I decided to ask again.
Given an infinite binary tree:

[Representation of infinite binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUBFy.png)

And two random nodes, u and v, find the shortest path between them(distance between node 1 and 2 is 1)in a very time efficient method.
I've currently tried this, but given sizes of up to 500.000 questions of u,v <2.000.000.000, it isn't efficient

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int Distance(int x,int y)
{
    int Levelx=log2(x);
    int Levely=log2(y);
    while(x!=y)
    {
        if(x<y)
            y/=2;
        if(x>y)
            x/=2;
    }
    int LevelOfLCA=log2(x);
    return Levelx+Levely-2*LevelOfLCA;
}
int main()
{
    int NumberOfQuestions;
    cin>>NumberOfQuestions;
    for(int i=1;i<=NumberOfQuestions;i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        cout<<Distance(x,y)<<'\n';
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me understand a better method of approaching this problem, as I couldn't understand templatetypedef's answer in [the previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960057/shortest-path-between-two-nodes-in-an-infinite-complete-binary-tree) asked.

Comment: You will be better off expanding on what you didn't understand about the other answer because the odds are high that any answer this question gets will put you in exactly the same predicament. If an answerer can zoom in what you didn't get, you'll get a much better answer and it will be easy to distinguish this question from the cited not-understood duplicate.

Comment: So how are we to help you if you linked to an answer already?  Even the title of the link is almost the same as your title.

Comment: You're right @user4581301, I should have mentioned that in the previous post, I didn't quite understand how the second solution worked and why it was faster than the first shown answer that I've already implemented in my code, more precisely how to do this step :"Therefore, we can binary search over the possible depths of the LCA for u and v, computing the ancestor of each node from that depth by using a bitshift... Compute the path from u to that ancestor by repeatedly shifting away one bit from u until we arrive at the common ancestor."

Comment: OK, so which part of _that_ is confusing? Be specific. Do you know _how_ to bitshift? Do you know _why_ to bitshift? (It's explained in that answer). Do you see why it's describing this walk as a binary search?

Comment: What do you mean "not efficient"?

Comment: You could win a bit with less portable instructions like clz.

Answer (score 0):

You're guaranteed that no matter which two nodes (A) and (B) in the tree you choose, they will both share a common ancestor-node (C).  In the worst-case, that node will be the root-node of the tree, but in other cases, it will be some other intermediate node that they are both a descendant of.

Therefore, your task is mainly just figuring out where that common ancestor-node (C) is; once you know it, computing the path-length between the two nodes is simply a matter of summing the distance (A to C) with the distance of (B to C)

One way to find the shared-ancestor node would be to simply start at both A and B, iterating upward via the parent-pointer of (whichever of the two nodes is deeper), and inserting a pointer to each parent-node you find into a `std::unordered_set<Node *>`, until you find a `Node *` that is already present in your `unordered_set`.  When you find that, that is your shared-ancestor node.

That will give you O(log(N)) performance, which is very fast, although it does presume that your nodes have parent-pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Breadth-first search.  It will work even if the tree is infinite and it's efficient.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that BFS would work faster as I am not actually using a <vector> with the connections between each nodes, but rather I'm trying to use the fact that I know a node x is connected to it's sons, x*2 and x*2+1, and is simultaneously the son of x/2.

Comment: In that case, isn't there a closed-form solution for the depths of the two nodes?